# Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest not working in Chrome Packaged App despite having url in permissions

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xss, google-chrome-app

I'm having a similar issue to this other question on SO, ["XMLHttpRequest not working in Google Chrome Packaged Web App"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375729/xmlhttprequest-not-working-in-google-chrome-packaged-web-app). However, the selected answer is not working for me. I do have the url that I'm trying to request listed in the manifest permissions. I have a feeling this has to do with cross-site-scripting prevention, as I read about in the [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) and [Embed Content](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html) docs for Chrome.

When I inspect the response, everything's empty, no `status` code, no `response`, no `statusText`, just like what happens when trying to make a request across domains as in XSS, as seen in this SO question: [Empty responseText from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941340/empty-responsetext-from-xmlhttprequest).

Here's my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name": "{name}",
    "description" : "{description}",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",

    "permissions": [
        "idle",
        "storage",
        "notifications",
        "https://prefix.domain.suffix/*",
        "https://prefix.domain.suffix/sub/"
    ],

    "app": {
        "background": {
          "scripts": ["models.js", "background.js"]
        }
    },


    "icons": { "16": "icon-16.png", "128": "icon-128.png" }
}
```

I'm using this function to do the requests:

```
function xhr(url, callback){
    var timeout= 2000;
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.ontimeout = function () {
        console.error("The request for " + url + " timed out.");
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(){
        console.error("error: "+xhr.statusText);
    }
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                window.console.log("response: "+xhr.response);
                callback(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.timeout = timeout;
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

The url I'm trying to request is fairly basic with some query string parameters tacked on the end and looks like this:

```
https://prefix.domain.suffix/sub/serve.aspx?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

Which, when loaded in the browser, returns simple and valid JSON:

```
{
    "ret" : [

        { "date": 1380603600000, "foo": bar1 }, 
        { "date": 1380776400000, "foo": bar2 }
    ]
}
```

The function I'm using to test in the developer console is this:

```
xhr('https://prefix.domain.suffix/sub/serve.aspx?param1=val1&param2=val2', function(e){ console.log(e); });
```

All that is printed to the console is `error:`, and `xhr` at that moment is:

`XMLHttpRequest {statusText: "", status: 0, response: "", responseType: "", responseXML: null…}`

One other thing which may need to be considered is that this url I'm requesting is behind authentication on my server. I'm logged in and am able to access the page, regardless of which tab I'm using, so I don't think that's the problem, but it still might be.

Comment: Apps don't share your browser's cookie store. They're like native apps in that respect. So your last paragraph is likely the issue. Change to a server that doesn't require authentication as a test to confirm it. Then investigate chrome.identity.

Comment: @sowbug, I'll give it a shot, but don't you think that if it was an authentication issue, there would be some kind of status code in the `xhr` object?

Comment: It's probably easier to try it than to speculate here. Let us know.

Comment: @sowbug, that was it! Now I'll just have to find out how I can authenticate.

Comment: @sowbug if you make an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps don't share your browser's cookie store. They're like native apps in that respect. So your last paragraph is likely the issue. Change to a server that doesn't require authentication as a test to confirm it. Then investigate chrome.identity.

Comment: but what would be your recommendation if a Chrome packaged app really *does* need Basic Auth over HTTPS instead of OAuth (eg. doing smart Http protocol clone of git repo from Github or Bitbucket) ? as chrome.identity is no help there...

Comment: That's a new question. Ask it!

Comment: yes good point! I did and in the process of writing it I figured out that solution, so thanks for the prompt... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798304/is-there-a-way-for-chrome-packaged-apps-to-handle-http-basicauthentication

Answer (score -2):

```
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
```

try this...

Comment: This won't fix the problem. I'm making a packaged Chrome app, which means that I'm guaranteed to have the XMLHttpRequest function, and this code will never be run on IE. Thanks for responding anyway.